# how to Json DeserializeObject specified type of string

Tags: c#, json

ok i'm trying to serialize object and deserialize it back,
i'm using these classes to handle receiving different types

```
    public class JsonWrapper
{
    public string ObjType { get; set; }
    public object Obj { get; set; }
}
public class JsonWrapper<T>
{
    public string ObjType => typeof(T).FullName;
    public T Obj { get; set; }
}
```

its working like that

```
        var wrapper = new JsonWrapper<Car> {Obj = new Car {model = 2012, Color = "red"}};
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapper);
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonWrapper>(serialized);
        var type = Type.GetType(deserialized.ObjType);
        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
            Convert.ToString(deserialized.Obj), type);
```

my problem is what if i want to use the wrapper for string type, if i tried the same way with string

```
        var wrapper = new JsonWrapper<string> {Obj = "hello"};
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapper);
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonWrapper>(serialized);
        var type = Type.GetType(deserialized.ObjType);
        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
            Convert.ToString(deserialized.Obj), type);
```

it doesn't work and get me error
`Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 1, position 1`
working with int as well so i wondering

Comment: You're not using `type` here, but what's the point of wrapping any primitive when it'll just be the same thing?

Comment: look once again please, i have edited the question @OneCricketeer

Comment: I'm still concerned why you think you need a wrapper.

Comment: because i want to receive different possible types, like string or exception..etc 
so i receive the wrapper to get the type name in the Json type field 
then DeserializeObject object with the type in the wrapper
@OneCricketeer

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding my opinions on whether or not you should be doing this or the usefulness of it.

**Given**

```
public class JsonWrapper<T>
{
   public string ObjType => typeof(T).FullName;
   public T Obj { get; set; }
}
```

**Unwrap method**

```
public static object UnWrap(string json)
{
   var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
   var objType = (string)jObject["ObjType"];

   if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objType)) 
      throw new InvalidOperationException("objType cannot be null or WhiteSpace");

   var type = Type.GetType(objType) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Type.GetType(objType)");

   var result = jObject["Obj"]?.ToObject(type) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("jObject[\"Obj\"]?.ToObject(type)");

   return result;
}
```

<sub>*Note : this was just a quick attempt at fault tolerance, the handling should likely be better with more appropriate exception type.*</sub>
**Usage**

```
var wrapper = new JsonWrapper<string> { Obj = "hello" };
var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapper);

var result = UnWrap(serialized);
Console.WriteLine(result.GetType().Name);

var wrapper2 = new JsonWrapper<Version> { Obj = new Version(1,2,3,4) };
var serialized2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapper2);

result = UnWrap(serialized2);
Console.WriteLine(result.GetType().Name);
```

**Output**

```
String
Version
```

Comment: gonna give it a try